# How to prevent the empty queue exception from queue.Peek()?

Tags: c#, methods, queue, peek

I'm making a 2D tower defense game for learning, and I'm following this tutorial:

http://xnatd.blogspot.com.br/2010/10/tutorial-9-multiple-waves.html

The code in there uses the Peek in the wave queue:

```
public Wave CurrentWave // Get the wave at the front of the queue

{
    get { return waves.Peek(); }
}

public List<Enemy> Enemies // Get a list of the current enemeies

{
    get { return CurrentWave.Enemies; }
}

public int Round // Returns the wave number

{
    get { return CurrentWave.RoundNumber + 1; }
}
```

But the problem is, when theres no more waves in the queue, it crashes:

*"An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dll
Additional information: Empty queue."*

And it uses this method in multiple parts of the code. I tried to place a IF before the GET like:

```
    public Wave CurrentWave // Get the wave at the front of the queue

    {
        if (waves.Count >= 1)
       {
        get { return waves.Peek(); }
       }
    }
```

But it seems it's not possible. I don't know how i can solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just place your 'if' *inside* the method body and it will be fine

The method begins with 'get {' and ends with '}'. That thing is called a property getter.

```
public Wave CurrentWave // Get the wave at the front of the queue
{    
    get 
    { 
       if (waves.Count >= 1)
       {
          return waves.Peek(); 
       }
       else
       {
          return null;
       }
    }
}
```

Then, modify two other getters to check CurrentWave for null and then return null.

Comment: It works but I'm forced to return something, so i made it return null or 0 in the else:

`public Wave CurrentWave
        {
            get {
                if (waves.Count >= 1)
                {
                    return waves.Peek();
                }

                else
                return null;
            }
        }`

Comment: Of course you are. If you don't want to return a signalling null (and then check for null) you can use the [Null object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) (i.e. return an empty instance of Wave class)